# How to see css file name in devtool without eject?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I have app created with `create-react-app`. Now I want to see exact file name in my chrome dev tool, but inessed of name e.g `App.js` I see useless `<style></style>`. So seems source map doesn't work or isn't enable in webpack by default. 1 or 2 years ago I fixed that by ejection. But I'm pretty use there is an easy way to archive that.

[image]